# Enabled systemd user service doesn't start at login

Tags: systemd

I want the user service `nfancurve.service` to start running every time I log in. I previously enabled the service using the command `systemctl --user enable nfancurve.service`, however, every time I start a new session (including reboots) the service isn't running, although it's enabled, which I verified by running these commands after logging in:

```
name@machine:~$ systemctl --user is-active nfancurve.service
inactive
name@machine:~$ systemctl --user is-enabled nfancurve.service
enabled
name@machine:~$ systemctl --user start nfancurve.service
name@machine:~$ systemctl --user is-active nfancurve.service
active
```

This is the status log from `systemctl --user status nfancurve.service`:

```
● nfancurve.service - Nfancurve service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/nfancurve.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

For full information, the service comes from [this repository](https://github.com/nan0s7/nfancurve), which I installed from the AUR. The `.service` file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nfancurve service
After=graphical-session.target
Requires=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/bin/nfancurve -c /etc/nfancurve.conf
KillSignal=SIGINT

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

I already tried changing the last line to `WantedBy=default.target`, but after rebooting and logging in the service still didn't start. My desktop environment is xfce, in case this is relevant considering the `graphical-session.target`.

How do I make sure it automatically starts up at every login?

Comment: What do the logs say? After you boot the system and the service isn't started, what is the output of `systemctl status nfancurve`? Add all of that to your question.

Comment: I added the output of `systemctl --user status nfancurve.service`, since it's a user service. `systemctl status nfancurve` outputs `Unit nfancurve.service could not be found.`.

Comment: If you `systemctl --user cat nfancurve.service`, What's in the `[Install]` section of the unit?

Comment: @fra-san It's from that project indeed, I installed it using the AUR and I just verified that `/usr/lib/systemd/user/nfancurve.service` (the unit file, I assume?) matches `nfancurve.service` from that repository. I'll add the information about the package and installation to my question.

Comment: @Stewart It's `WantedBy=graphical-session.target`.

Comment: Thanks. In light of Stewart's answer, it may be useful to also add your desktop environment to your question. Also, have you checked the log after changing the `WantedBy` directive? (If needed, you can list the complete log with `journalctl --user -b 0 -u nfancurve`).

Comment: It's xfce, I added it to the question. The log is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution (thanks to Stewart and others). I changed the original service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nfancurve service
After=graphical-session.target
Requires=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/bin/nfancurve -c /etc/nfancurve.conf
KillSignal=SIGINT

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

by removing the Requires-line and replacing all instances of `graphical-session.target` by `default.target`(both the `After` and `WantedBy` lines). This leads to my current service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nfancurve service
After=default.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/bin/nfancurve -c /etc/nfancurve.conf
KillSignal=SIGINT

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Now the service is active when I start my machine and log in.

Answer (score 11):

## tl;dr

Change `WantedBy=graphical-session.target` to `WantedBy=default.target`.

## Hypothesis

I suspect your problem is with the `[Install]` section of your service file.  Installing it based on `multi-user.target` might be quite normal for system units, but the equivalent for user-units is `default.target`.  See the [systemd.special(7) manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#Special%20User%20Units) for details.

```
| system target     | near-equivalent user target |
|-------------------|-----------------------------|
| multi-user.target | default.target              |
| graphical.target  | graphical-session.target    |
```

Other targets that may also be interesting to you are `graphical-session-pre.target` or `xdg-desktop-autostart.target`.

## default.target MVCE

Here's a minimal example I just tried on my Debian 11 machine:

The service file:

```
$ systemctl --user cat simpleuser.service
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/simpleuser.service
[Unit]
Description=Simple User Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I installed it with:

```
$ systemctl --user enable simpleuser.service
Created symlink /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/simpleuser.service → /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/simpleuser.service.
```

I performed a reboot and I can see that the service is active:

```
$ systemctl --user status simpleuser.service
● simpleuser.service - Simple User Service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/stew/.config/systemd/user/simpleuser.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable>
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-07-12 10:12:54 CEST; 13min left
    Process: 1127 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1127 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 12 10:12:54 stewbian systemd[1106]: Starting Simple User Service...
Jul 12 10:12:54 stewbian systemd[1106]: Finished Simple User Service.
```

If you're wondering about the `(exited)` substate: If you use something like `Type=simple` and `ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity`, then you'll get `(running)` instead.

## graphical-session.target problems

I found your question in the form of a bug report [on github](https://github.com/nan0s7/nfancurve/issues/33).

If you're installing based on graphical-session.target, then it's possible that isn't starting.  I just ran this on my KDE/i3 setup and reproduced on a vanilla Gnome3 setup.

```
$ systemctl --user status graphical-session.target
● graphical-session.target - Current graphical user session
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/graphical-session.target; static; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

It sounds like DEs don't really implement this target per its design.  In that case, you may be better-off using `WantedBy=default.target`.  Your script doesn't look GUI-based so I bet `default.target` would be fine.  Otherwise, you could consider using `After=graphical.target` in your `[Unit]` section.

According to [systemd.special(7) manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#Special%20User%20Units), `graphical-session.target` should be `BoundBy=` the DE (i.e. `{gnome,kde,xfce}-session.target`). This way, when Gnome starts, it will raise graphical-session.target.  When I inspect the dbus objects I clearly see no relationships with any target which would raise it.

```
$ busctl introspect --user org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/graphical_2dsession_2etarget \
    org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit
NAME                             TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE                             FLAGS
.ActiveState                     property  s         "inactive"                               emits-change
.After                           property  as        2 "simpleuser.service" "basic.target"    const
.Before                          property  as        1 "shutdown.target"                      const
.BindsTo                         property  as        0                                        const
.BoundBy                         property  as        0                                        const
.Conflicts                       property  as        1 "shutdown.target"                      const
.ConsistsOf                      property  as        2 "gnome-terminal-server.service" "duns… const
.Description                     property  s         "Current graphical user session"         const
.Documentation                   property  as        1 "man:systemd.special(7)"               const
.LoadState                       property  s         "loaded"                                 const
.Names                           property  as        1 "graphical-session.target"             const
.PartOf                          property  as        0                                        const
.RequiredBy                      property  as        0                                        const
.Requires                        property  as        1 "basic.target"                         const
.SubState                        property  s         "dead"                                   emits-change
.UnitFilePreset                  property  s         "disabled"                               -
.UnitFileState                   property  s         "static"                                 -
.WantedBy                        property  as        0                                        const
.Wants                           property  as        1 "simpleuser.service"                   const
```

I did some digging into the mailing lists and found that `{gnome,kde,xfce}-session.target` was proposed only four years ago with the intention that gnome, kde, xfce would ship the `*.target` files.  It hasn't happened (yet). Therefore, even though it's documented, it's incomplete. Therefore you shouldn't use `graphical-session.target` yet.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I changed the `[Install]` section following your suggestion, but the problem persists. However, I also found the lines `After=graphical-session.target` and `Requires=graphical-session.target` in the `[Unit]` section, should these be modified too?

Comment: Yes,  Though, I think you can delete `Requires=`.  Also, I think you can change `After=graphical-session.target` to `After=graphical.target` if you really want to prevent the script from running before the desktop environment starts.

Answer (score 0):

Your .service file should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Spark service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/spark/sbin/start-all.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, take a few more steps to enable and use the .service file:

1. Place it in /etc/systemd/system folder with say a name of myfirst.service
2. Make sure that your script executable with: `chmod u+x /path/to/spark/sbin/start-all.sh`
3. Start it: `sudo systemctl start myfirst`
4. Enable it to run at boot: `sudo systemctl enable myfirst`
5. Stop it: `sudo systemctl stop myfirst`

Comment: `multi-user.target` is only applicable for system-wide services.  OP is specifically asking about user services.